# Why can I receive touch event after popScene in cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have two `Scene`, one is `WallScene` and another is `ExeScene`. When I click in `WallScene`, I pushScene `ExeScene`

```
CCDirector::sharedDirector()->pushScene(ExeScene::create(hanzi));
```

And I popScene in one of the `Layer` in `WallScene`. And in my `ExeScene`, I have four Layers

- BackgroundLayer
- HLayer
- TLayer
- TouchLayer

I handle touch event in TouchLayer. However, I can still receive touch event in `TouchLayer` when I pop ExeScene.

Comment: A common problem in cocos2d-iphone is overriding onEnter/onExit but not calling the super (base class) implementation, leaving cocos2d unresponsive to touches.

Comment: For testing purposes .. try using replaceScene instead of push/pop. I've had cleanup issues in the past while using the push/pop approach.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Thanks,my problem is what you said. I didn't call super implementation in OnEnter/onExit function.